# Configure Emergency Alerts on Android Pie

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie, alerts

My phone is in either vibrate or DND mode at night. I enabled developer mode in order to be able to allow the emergency alerts to ignore DND, since otherwise they make no sound at night (don't know why this requires developer mode, I would have thought it would be the default setting).

I would like more fine-grained control than just that setting. When I'm sleeping, there's no reason for me to be woken up by one of the frequent Amber alerts, since I'm not going to be much help from my bed. If there's an Incoming Ballistic Missile alert on the other hand, I wouldn't mind be roused for that.

Currently, it seems that I have the following options:

1. Prevent all alerts from breaking through DND - *Makes alerts useless*
2. Allow all alerts to break through DND - *Get woken up constantly by
   Amber alerts*
3. Turn off Amber alerts and allow other alerts to break
   through DND - *Prevents me from helping with Amber alerts when I'm out
   of the house*

Is there a way to configure the alert settings between the various types of emergency alert in Android 9? Maybe an app that give me better control? I'm using an Essential PH-1, if the phone type matters.

Comment: Are you sure the emergency message system is used in your region and by your mobile network operator? Some countries/regions do use an app-based emergency notification system instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm in Canada. I do receive messages from the emergency message system (I've received some severe weather alerts and many Amber alerts)